# Extracting integers from a string and forming actual numbers from a list of these integers

Tags: python, string

I have a string `bar`:

```
bar = 'S17H10E7S5E3H2S105H90E15'
```

I take this string and form groups that start with the letter `S`:

```
groups = ['S' + elem for elem in bar.split('S') if elem != '']
groups
['S17H10E7', 'S5H3E2', 'S105H90E15']
```

**Without using the mini-language RegEx**, I'd like to be able to get the integer values that follow the different letters `S`, `H`, and `E` in these `groups`.  To do so, I'm using:

```
code = 'S'
temp_num = []

for elem in groups:
    start = elem.find(code)
    for char in elem[start + 1: ]:
        if not char.isdigit():
            break
        else:
            temp_num.append(char)
            num_tests = ','.join(temp_num)
```

This gives me:

```
print(groups)
['S17H10E7', 'S5H3E2', 'S105H90E15']

print(temp_num)
['1', '7', '5', '1', '0', '5']

print(num_tests)
1,7,5,1,0,5
```

How would I take these individual integers `1`, `7`, `5`, `1`, `0`, and `5` and put them back together to form a list of the digits following the code `S`?  For example:

```
[17, 5, 105]
```

**UPDATE**:

In addition to the accepted answer, here is another solution:

```
def count_numbers_after_code(string_to_read, code):
    
    index_values = [i for i, char in enumerate(string_to_read) if char == code]
    
    temp_1 = []    
    temp_2 = []
   
    for idx in index_values:
        temp_number = []
        for character in string_to_read[idx + 1: ]:
            if not character.isdigit():
                break
            else:
                temp_number.append(character)

            temp_1 = ''.join(temp_number)
        temp_2.append(int(temp_1))
    
    return sum(temp_2)
```

Comment: how about `s = [z for x in bar.split('S') for y in x.split('H') for z in y.split('E') if z]; [s[i::3] for i in range(3)]`

Comment: Are you not allowed to use regular expressions here?

Comment: I'd rather not use RegEx (unless absolutely necessary).

Comment: @enke -- this gives me everything.  I was looking to get only the values associated with a particular code.  Also, the length of `bar` is variable (doesn't have to consist of 3 groups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
def get_numbers_after_letter(letter, bar):
    current = True
    out = []
    for x in bar:
        if x==letter:
            out.append('')
            current = True
        elif x.isnumeric() and current:
            out[-1] += x
        elif x.isalpha() and x!=letter:
            current = False
    return list(map(int, out))
```

Output:

```
>>> get_numbers_after_letter('S', bar)
[17, 5, 105]

>>> get_numbers_after_letter('H', bar)
[10, 3, 90]

>>> get_numbers_after_letter('E', bar)
[7, 2, 15]
```

I think it's better to get all the numbers after every letter, since we're making a pass over the string anyway but if you don't want to do that, I guess this could work.

Answer (score 1):

The question states that you would favour a solution without using regex ("unless absolutely necessary" from the comments)

It is not necessary of course, but as an alternative for future readers you can match `S` and capture 1 or more digits using `(\d+)` in a group that will be returned by re.findall.

```
import re

bar = 'S17H10E7S5E3H2S105H90E15'
print(re.findall(r"S(\d+)", bar))
```

Output

```
['17', '5', '105']
```